# Transactionscope and deadlocks when using enterprise library

Tags: c#, enterprise-library, deadlock, transactionscope

We are using Enterprise Library for data access.

One of our methods has a delete and then an insert, against the same table. This gives a deadlock.

If we put these inside a transaction scope the deadlock no longer occurs.

Intuitively, it feels like it should be the opposite way around. Can anyone explain why it works like this?

Comment: Check [`Isolation Level`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel.aspx) in yoru C# code as well as [`Stored procedures`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Transaction scope combined with `TransactionOptions` `IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted` is equivalent to WITH(NOLOCK) in T-SQL so if the table is not locked the deadlocks don't occur...

```
using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions(){ IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
{
}
```

Comment: -1: The default isolation level for `TransactionScope` is `Serializable`.  See Setting the TransactionScope isolation level in the article [Implementing an Implicit Transaction using Transaction Scope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172152.aspx)

Comment: @RandyLevy, Yes, TransactionOptions with ReadUncommitted IsolationLevel must be used as well, corrected the answer.